# Создание route mvc

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, route

Понимаю, что наболевшая тема, и много (очень много) примеров есть в интернете.

Дело в том, что у меня есть роуты, но они кривые (сам код плохой).
Вид следующий:

```
 array(new Route('/url','className','methodName'));
```

и массив через new Router;

Суть в том, чтобы все работало, мне нужно еще создавать отдельный файл и прописывать туда два метода:

```
__construct($args=[]) {$this->args = $args}
```

и метод, для создания экземпляра класса с названием класса, параметрами и экшеном.

В любом случае, то что выше - не совсем важно.

Суть в том, что это как-бы мой опыт в написании роутинга, и у меня в голове насильно засел данный способ, увы.

Как можно нормально написать подобную систему? Не используя доп.классов, т.е:
два класса Route, Router:

```
$router = [new Route('/','main','index')];
new Router($router);
```

P.s: не прошу за меня писать, просто "толкните" на размышление.
Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Приветствую!

MVC - означает, что у вас есть контроллеры для работы с сайтом, модели предоставляющие данные, и вьюхи для их отображения.

По идее, структура каталогов для скриптов может быть что-то вроде:

```
\Core
    //базовые классы
    Controller.php 
    Model.php
    View.php
    //и роутер
    Route.php
\Controllers
    //тут должны лежать контроллеры, для примера положу блог.пхп для блога
    blog.php
    error404.php
\Models
    //тут должны лежать модели, для примера положу модель блог.пхп для блога
    blog.php
\Views 
    //тут должны лежать вьюхи, для примера положу пару вьюх для блога
    //я тут показал файлы html, но тут могут быть и файлы php
    blog_index.html
    blog_post.html
    error404.html
\More 
    //в этой папке пускай будут лежать какие-нибудь дополнительные классы
```

Первым делом нужно прописать автолоадер, чтобы нам не изобретать велосипед и включать классы по желанию (нужно включить в индексный файл):

**autodoader.php***

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $file = SITE_DIR.'/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $class).'.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) require_once $file;
});
```

Базовые классы (в них, по идее, нужно определить какой-то базовый функционал):

**\Core\Controller.php**

```
<?php
namespace Core;
abstract class Controller
{
    public View = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }

    abstract function init();
}
```

**\Core\Model.php**

```
<?php
namespace Core;
abstract class Model
{
}
```

**\Core\View.php**

```
<?php
namespace Core;
class View
{
    public function addTemplate($template)
    {
        //тут нужно описать процедуру подгрузки шаблона
    }

    public function addView($view)
    {
        //тут нужно описать процедуру подгрузки вьюхи
    }

    public function show()
    {
        //тут нужно сделать вывод контента
    }
}
```

По сути ваш класс View может быть оболочкой над каким-то шаблонизатором для более удобной работы с ним. В этом случае очень рекомендую не писать своего шаблонизатора, а использовать что-то готовое. Из готовых мне больше всего нравится **Twig**.

Далее нужно брать полученный URL и из него извлекать путь для вызова нужного контроллера:

**\Core\Route.php**

```
<?php
namespace Core;
class Route
{
    static public $routes = null;

    static function start()
    {
        if (self::$routes == null) {
            $url = explode('?', substr(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1)));
            self::$routes = explode('/', $url[0]);
        }
        $controller_name = 'main';
        $action_name = 'index';

        if (!empty(self::$routes[0])) {
            $controller_name = self::$routes[0];
        }

        if (!empty(self::$routes[1])) {
            $action_name = self::$routes[1];
        }

        $controller_class = '\\Controllers\\'.$controller_name;
        $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;

        $controller = new $controller_class;

        if(method_exists($controller, $action_name)) {
            $controller->$action_name();
        }
        else {
            Route::Error404();
        }
    }

    public static function Error404() {
        $protocol = 'http';
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443) $protocol = 'https';
        $host = $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        header('Location:'.$host.'/error404');
    }
}
```

**\Controllers\error404.php**

```
<?php
namespace Controllers;
class error404 extends \Core\Controller
{
    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->View->addTemplate('basic');
        $this->View->addView('error404');
        $this->View->show();
    }
}
```

**\Views\error404.html**

```
<h1>Ошибка 404</h1>
<p>Страница не доступна или не существует.</p>
```

И, собственно у вас должен быть какой-то **index.php** (или какой-то другой файл), который будет все инициировать.

```
<?php
include "autoloader.php";

\Core\Route()::start();
```

**ВАЖНО!** Хоть я и влез в некоторые подробности, я лишь хотел натолкнуть вас на некую идею автоматизации. Реализовать роутинг так же можно с помощью файлов (прописывая пути в некий файл/файлы роутинга, в качестве примера, можно посмотреть Symfony). В любом случае, код я писал прямо тут, не проверяя его работоспособность. Так же не настаиваю на его идеальности.

Буду рад, если смог как-то помочь.

Comment: Просто из любопытства - почему названия директорий (Core, Controllers и т.д.) с заглавной?

Comment: Можно и с маленькой, конечно. Просто когда-то читал пср (это стандарты или, по другому, правила хорошего тона)... Почитайте сами, посмотрите приведенные примеры (первая ссылка, что выдал поисковик) http://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Просто считал, что при прочих равных, вариант с заглавной это лишнее нажатие shift.

Comment: Да в psr2 есть стандарт именования классов, без namespace точнее они писались в название класса к приммеру класс с именем `Core_App_Abstract` лежит в файле `Core/App/Abstract.php` так же и namespace класс `Core\App\AbstractClass` будет лежать в `Core/App/AbstractClass.php` так интуинтивно понятно где находиться фаил с классом. В последнем заменил `Abstract` на `AbstractClass` т.к. `Abstract` это ключевое слово в php. @VladimirGamalian

Comment: p.s. К стати в php есть константа DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR и именно её лучше использовать в автолоадере.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я уже разобрался)
Посидел часиков до 5 утра и решил проблему, вроде бы все хорошо работает, поправил.
Вот теперь вопрос истекает:
Фрейм я пилю конечно для себя(не собираюсь лить на гит и т.п)но все же не хотелось бы с самого начала "плохо" набивать руку.
У меня тут в голову лезет две вещи:У меня будет controlller.php и Model.php, собственно, эти два класса(в файлах) будут абстрактными, а все остальные контроллеры и модели(по типу, контроллер для user, модель для статей и т.п) будут наследоваться от них.Или же, лучше создать один трейт и отписать там, все что мне нужно?

Comment: @DeadMoras, я не могу дать вам конкретные рекомендации, т.к. не знаю всех особенностей вашего проекта (да и нет особого желания погружаться). Плюсы и минусы есть и там и там.